# how to pass new query to Flexigrid?

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

im trying to pass new query to FlexiGrid using this code:

```
$('#fgAllPatients').flexReload({ query: 'blah=qweqweqwe' });
```

but when it goes back to the webservice, it simply gets the old parameter and this new one is neglected. help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to do it like this

```
 $('#fgAllPatients').flexOptions({ query: 'blah=qweqweqwe' }).flexReload();
```

sorry so late haven't been paying attention to this tag lately